# How do you change backgroundtint colour if there is text in EditText Field?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Good Afternoon, I want to trigger my button to change colours after there is text in my editText field im wondering how do you do this check constantly, instead of the one time the fragment boots up?

My fragment code

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navc = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        registerObservers()
        setListeners(view)
        onTextChanged()
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            navc!!.navigate(R.id.orderListFragment)
        }
    }

    private fun registerObservers() {
        accountViewModel.profile.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        }
    }

    private fun onTextChanged() {
        if (restaurantEmail.editableText.isNotEmpty()) {
            sendHtmlcode.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.standardOrange))
        }else{
            println("Testingprint")
            sendHtmlcode.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.standardGrey))

        }
```

It colours up the first time without text but after that it doesnt check again and I dont understand why not

Answer (score 0):

You can use `doOnTextChanged` function which trigger everytime text in EditText changes. It internally uses a `TextWatcher`.

```kotlin
editText.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count -> 
    onTextChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `doOnTextChange` this is a kotlin extension fuction of textView.

```
import androidx.core.widget.doOnTextChanged

yourEditText.doOnTextChange { text, start, before, count ->
  // here you check if the input is empty
  onTextChanged(text.isNotEmpty())
}

private fun onTextChanged(isNotEmpty: Boolean) {
    if (isNotEmpty) {
        sendHtmlcode.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.standardOrange))
    }else{
        println("Testingprint")
        sendHtmlcode.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.standardGrey))

    }
}
```